# Automate clicking of dialog Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ui-automation

I'm looking for a cross-platform way to automatically click the 'Add extension' or 'Allow' permissions dialog on Chrome.

I know you can start Chrome with --load-extension, but in this case I'm looking for an automation script that will detect this dialog and will press the button.

I tried RAutomation, but for some reason it does not detect the dialog.

Comment: Which platforms do you need to cover?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Windows/Ubuntu/OSX - I'm currently trying with SikuliX which seems promising